# Influxdb time range query

Tags: python-3.x, influxdb, influxdb-python, influxql

I am trying to form a sql query for the below  condition in where clause but it is giving an error.

```
date(\"time\") BETWEEN date_trunc('month', current_date - INTERVAL '1 months') \
            AND (date_trunc('MONTH', current_date - INTERVAL '1 months' + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day'))
```

Influxdb query which I am trying and it is giving an error is as below.

```
SELECT * FROM "series" WHERE time >= (now() - 30d) AND time < (now() - (30d + 30d - 1d))
```

But above query is giving badrequest error. Could you please help me to correct this query.

Answer (score 0):

The time clause in the InfluxQL query is unfulfillable, time lower and upper bounds seems reversed. Or the comparison operators are, depending on your coding preferences.